Concurvity values above and below main diagonal, what means each side?
When I calculate concurvity(), for a GAM model from mgcv package, using full=F, I get 3 matrices but what do the values ​​above and below the main diagonal in each matrix mean?
I understood on the worst estimate they are simetric, but the estimate and observed values not. How should I interpret these values?
